# How to check if a given floating point number has numbers up till 1 decimal place in Java?

Tags: floating-point, precision

One of my friends asked to me to write a program that takes a floating point number and tells if it has numbers up till 1 decimal place. This is the program that I made:

```
class test
{
  static void main(double a)
  {
    double test_a=100*a;
    if(test_a%10==0)
      System.out.println("The given number has numbers up till 1 decimal place");
    else
      System.out.println("The given number has number up till more than 1 decimal place");
  }
}
```

How it works is if the given number has numbers up till 1 decimal place (say 4.6), 100 times that number gives a number divisible by 10 (4.6×100=460). But if the given number doesn't have numbers up till 1 decimal place (say 4.61), 100 times that number gives a number which isn't divisible by 10 (4.61×100=461). I used the same basis in my program above.

But it doesn't seem to work. For any floating point number, it outputs that "The given number has number up till more than 1 decimal place". But for integers, it outputs "The given number has number up till 1 decimal place".

Why is this really happening and how can I create this program ?

Comment: You seem to multiply with 100 instead of 10?

Comment: The only Java `double` numbers with zero or one decimal places are the integers and numbers ending in .5. No other fractions are representable in the base-two format Java uses. For example, input of “1.1” will produce the `double` value 1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625, and multiplying that by 100 yields 110.0000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625. You cannot do decimal arithmetic in base-two floating-point without understanding the format and the arithmetic rules and compensating for the discrepancies.

Comment: Addendum: The “No other fractions are representable“ above is in the context of numbers with zero or one digits after the decimal point. For two digits, .25 and .75 are also representable (in addition to .00 and .50). For three, .125, .375, .625, and .875 are representable, and so on.

Comment: @StefanHaustein Yes 100, it is how multiplying the number by 100 works.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ok, I understand now. So is there any way of creating the program without this problem ?

Comment: If you set a limit on how big the number can be and the lowest digit you will support, and they are close enough together, then you can use properties of the floating-point format and its operations to know that rounding errors caused by the floating-point operations will not interfere with the results.

Comment: For example, if the `double` format is the IEEE-754 binary format, and the maximum number you will support is less than 2^20 = 1,048,576, then the most rounding error there can be in converting some supported number to `double` is 2^−34, about 5.82e-11. (This is because the format has 53 bits of precision, the highest bit in numbers less than 2^20 is 2^19, so the lowest bit is at least 2^(19−52) = 2^−33, and conversion never has to round more than ½ the distance between representable numbers, so at most 2^−34.

Comment: Then, if you multiply the number by 10, it should be near an integer if the original decimal number (that was converted to a `double`) had one digit after the decimal point. Multiplying by 10 can produce numbers up to 2^20•10, which can have bit 2^23 set, so the lowest representable bit is 2^(23−52) = 2^−29, so rounding error can be at most 2^−30. Also, the original conversion error has been multiplied by 10, so our bound on that is 2^−34•10. Therefore, if the original number had at most one decimal point, the result of converting it to `double` and multiplying by 10 is within 2^−30+2^−34•10.

Comment: So, let’s say you take the number, multiply by 10 (call that x), round to an integer (call that y), and check |y−x|. If it is less than 2^−30+2^−34•10, you report yes, the original number had at most one digit after the decimal point. We know that test will always report true if the original number had at most one digit after the decimal point. The next question is how to prevent it from reporting true if the number had more digits after the decimal point? Consider 9.000000000000000000001. When convert and multiplied, it will be closer to an integer than our bound.

Comment: Recall I said you need to set a limit on the lowest digit you will support. If the lowest digit position supported is 10^−n, then then a 1 in that position, or a bunch of 9’s leading up to that position, can produce a number that is 10^(−n+1) in y (plus possibly some effects of rounding I am not going to examine in these comments). So we need 10^(−n+1) to be outside that bound we calculated, 2^−30+2^−34•10, to guarantee that these extra digits push the number far enough away from an integer that we can detect it. 2^−30+2^−34•10 is less than 10^−9, so −n+1=−9, n=10 might suffice.

Comment: So, if I have done the arithmetic correctly, then, if the original number is less than 2^20 and has at most 10 digits after the decimal point, then taking the value that results from converting it to `double` and multiplying by 10 and testing if the product is within 2^−30+2^−34•10 of an integer will correctly indicate whether the original number at had most one digit after the decimal point.